# Rails calling the edit action within a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, crud

I am sure this is common requirement but I am new to rails and I have tried searching for the problem but haven't had much luck.

I have a form and I have pre-populated it with values from the database for the specific entry. The user should be able to change those values and then hit the 'edit' button which then then go and edit the values in the database.

I want to call the edit action from within a page without using the standard /1/edit url path. Basically I want to call .find(params[:id]) by passing the id of a particular entry directly into the method.

What is the best 'rails way' of doing this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't understand the question; what do you actually want to have happen?

Comment: this sounds like you are up to doing something very wrong (but as Dave, I do not really understand the question). Could you explain, why you think you need to do this? There is most likely a better way. If there is functionality in edit which you need at other places, you most likely should refactor it into a model or some dedicated class.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, I have added some more information to my question. I want a button at the end of a form which will edit the database depending on the values in the fields, without leaving the page. Does this answer your questions?

Comment: So you just want a remote form? Pretty much a matter of adding the remote form parameter, modulo making sure you get back what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This particular method is being called within a button press? A link click? A focus change?

You can always send parameters to the server like this:

```
<%= link_to "Your action", yourcustomaction_path(:id => @object.id) %>
```

Or like this:

```
<%= text_field_tag "yourattribute", params[:this_field_attribute] %>
```

You don't have to always call the default edit action, you can simply create another route in routes.rb

Answer (score 0):

Or you could go one step further and use the in_place_editing gem. No need for a button and remote forms.